# Leibniz' differential notation inconsistency

Tags: calculus, notation, math-history

I have been researching the history of calculus (which means watching various math youtubes) and thinking about differential arguments involving $dx$ and $dy$. I noticed that in the quotient rule for differentials we cannot so easily ignore a term consistently.
$$ d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) = \frac{x + dx}{y+dy}- \frac{x}{y} = \frac{y (x + dx) - x (y + dy)}{y (y + dy)}= \frac{y~dx - x~dy  }{y^2 + \color{red}{y~dy}} $$

Why do we ignore the $\color{red}{y~dy}$ term in the denominator, but not the $y~dx$ , $x ~ dy$ terms in the numerator? We see from the numerator that we ought not to ignore products of variables and differentials, otherwise we would obtain $ 0/y^2 = 0$ . I can understand ignoring the product of two differentials, which comes up in the derivation of the differential product rule. viz.,  $d(x\cdot  y) = (x + \Delta x )(y + \Delta y) - x~ y= x  ~ \Delta y + y ~ \Delta x + \Delta x ~ \Delta y   $. It makes sense to ignore the last term, $\Delta x ~ \Delta y$, because it is a second order vanishingly small zero-approaching quantity. So we could say first order behavior dominates. Does $y^2$ dominate over $y ~dy$ in the quotient?

Comment: You're almost done. Of your quantity you need to keep only first order terms. Now expand the denominator. You will get $1/y^2+O(dy)$. Multiply and discard terms of second order or higher.

Comment: @lcv the $y ~dy$ term in the denominator is not a second order term, i painted it red. Maybe, rather it is $O(y)$.

Comment: As I wrote, it's a first order term. But the numerator is at least first order, so when you multiply you get at least second order contributions

Comment: @lcv the denominator is $ y( y+ \Delta y) $. Where is your second order term?

Comment: @john $y dy$ is not a second-term order. However $y^2$ is a term of order zero (if $y \neq 0$) and therefore, you can remove $y dy$, which is of order one , as $\lim_{dy \to 0} (y^2 + ydy) = y^2$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net why don't we do the same in the numerator, take the $\lim_{dx \to 0}$

Comment: Because in the numerator, there is no term of order zero.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net what about $x~ dy$ and $y ~dx$. they are not terms of order zero?

Comment: No! Of order one. A constant is of order zero.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net can you define order zero and order one. you're referring to big Oh notation? According to this link , order one is constant. https://www.happycoders.eu/algorithms/big-o-notation-time-complexity/

Comment: @john Please have a look in detail at Taylor expansion. In $a_0 + a_1 (dx) + a_2 (dx)^2+\dots...$, $a_0$ is of order zero, $a_1 (dx)$ of order one, and so on.

Comment: The article you refer to, is completely off the topic we're dealing with. For example, with that article, order two $O(2)$ would be equal to order one. You're mixing two many topics! I would suggest that you focus of derivatives and Taylor here.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net so are you saying that in the numerator we have order one taylor infinitsimal terms, in the denominator we have order zero terms. and order zero terms dominate over order one (or higher order) infinitesimal terms?

Comment: @john That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
 d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) &=  \frac{y~dx - x~dy  }{y^2 + ydy} \\
&= \left( y~dx - x~dy \right) \left( \frac{1}{y^2} + O(dy) \right) \\
&= \frac{y~dx - x~dy}{y^2} + O(d^2)
\end{align}

where I indicated with $O(d^2)$ terms of second order or higher.

Comment: Just checking , should that term on second line be "$\left( y~dx - x~dy \right) \left( \frac{1}{y^2} +\large{ \frac{1}{O(dy) }}\right) $" , since the $dy$ is in the denominator .

Comment: No. Have you ever heard of the geometric series? In any case: $1/(A+B) = \frac{1}{A(1+A^{-1}B)} = (1/A) (\sum_{n=0} (-A^{-1}B)^n$ $=1/A - A^{-2}B +O(B^2)$

Comment: yes, i have heard of geometric series. I think i will leave your ad-hoc train of reasoning alone. I will stick to limits. thanks anyway